# How to undo a radio button selection using JavaScript or preferably jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working in a scenario with a group of radio button selections.
The requirement is that only 2 can be selected Yes.
So, if the third is also selected "Yes", I want to revert it to "No"

Additionally I would also like to know if I can just check if a given index of Radio button within a group is checked instead of doing this:
"($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'Y')"

jsFiddle Link:  http://jsfiddle.net/pshah331/S8qep/

HTML:

```
<p>Folder A:
    <input type="radio" name="folder_A" value="Y" onclick="folderSelectionChanged()" />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="folder_A" value="N" onclick="folderSelectionChanged()" />No</p>
<p>Folder B:
    <input type="radio" name="folder_B" value="Y" onclick="folderSelectionChanged()" />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="folder_B" value="N" onclick="folderSelectionChanged()" />No</p>
<p>Folder C:
    <input type="radio" name="folder_C" value="Y" onclick="folderSelectionChanged()" />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="folder_C" value="N" onclick="folderSelectionChanged()" />No</p>
<div id="update"></div>
```

JavaScript in "HEAD":

```
function folderSelectedYesCount() {
    var yesCount = 0;
    var folderRadioGroups = $("input[name^='folder_']");


    folderRadioGroups.each(function () {
        // TODO:  Would like to check by index --> "index 0 is selected/checked"
        if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'Y') {
            yesCount++;
        }
    });

    return yesCount;
}

function folderSelectionChanged() {
    // TODO:  If count of Yes is greater than 2, then change the last clicked to "No"
    /*
    if (folderSelectedYesCount() > 1){
        $(this)[1].prop('checked', true);
    }
    */

    $('#update').html('Selection count for "Yes" is <b>' + folderSelectedYesCount() + ' </b>');
}
```

Comment: $(":radio[value='Y']:checked").length >=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your jsfiddle please check :-

```
function folderSelectionChanged(e) {

    if(folderSelectedYesCount()>2){
        $(e).siblings().prop("checked",true);         
    }
    $('#update').html('Selection count for "Yes" is <b>' + folderSelectedYesCount() + ' </b>');
}
```

click here :-http://jsfiddle.net/S8qep/47/

Thanks

Comment: Thanks.  How would the siblings() function work if there were more than 2 options?  I was thinking about using something like the "nth()" option.

Comment: you can also use this if there can be more option and you want to select the last one then do like this:-
$(e).siblings(":last") see the working example http://jsfiddle.net/S8qep/53/

Comment: if you want to select the index based option if it has more option then $(e).siblings(":eq(1)").prop("checked",true)   pass index in eq method

Answer (score 1):

Changed html so `folderSelectionChanged` function can take `this` as argument to handle the events like this:

```
if(folderSelectedYesCount() > 2){
    $(obj).prop('checked', false);
    $(obj).next().prop('checked', true);
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S8qep/45/)

Comment: Uh...I don't think this is a completely successful implementation. Try selecting Yes-No-Yes, and you should see some problematic behaviour.